# VBA: Enter Parameter Value on third command

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, parameters

I have a form with 3 commands on it, all should take you to a different form after data has been input by a user, and saved to the current record. My problem is, the second portion of the code is giving me an error and a parameter pop up appears when I select that command.

```
Private sub command2_click()
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = false
DoCmd.OpenForm “6_Prem_Conv”,,,”[ID]=“&Me.ID
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End sub

Private sub command3_click()
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:=“6_FEHB”
End sub

Private sub command4_click()
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = false
DoCmd.OpenForm “8_FEHB_Payment”,,,”[ID]=“&Me.ID
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End sub
```

Both command2 and command 3 seem to work fine, but the middle statement (DoCmd.openform) portion of command4 is giving me the parameter pop up.

Comment: I can only guess that `8_FEHB_Payment` needs more input than you are supplying with the current supplied parameters `,,,”[ID]=“&Me.ID`

Comment: Must be some field name in report design Access cannot find.